# Redirect Laravel Email verification with expired token - 403 | Invalid Signature

Tags: laravel

I noticed that when an email verification token expires in Laravel, it shows an error page which says

> 403 | Invalid Signature

I don't think its a good user experience for users, because the information is not clear to the user and they don't know what to do next.

Is it possible to redirect to  `/email/verify`

or customize the error message?

Comment: what version of Laravel?

Comment: Laravel Version 6.9.0

Comment: its your controller so you are more than welcome to modify the functionality as you see fit

Comment: Can you explain more please.

Comment: i am guessing the confusion is because of the use of the trait?

Comment: It's confusing. I end up increasing the Email Verification Expiration Time temporarily

Comment: ill give you something that would work ... hold on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still wanted to keep that behavior of what the trait is providing but you want to catch that exception and do something specific instead you can define your own `verify` method and aliasing the `verify` method from the trait so you can still use it:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class VerificationController extends Controller
{
    use VerifiesEmails {
        verify as verifyTrait;
    }

    ...

    public function verify(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            return $this->verifyTrait($request);
        } catch (AuthorizationException $e) {
            return ; // what ever you would like to do on failure
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for something like this, here is a possible solution according to the [Laravel 10 Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/urls#responding-to-invalid-signed-routes).

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\InvalidSignatureException;
/**
 * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
 */
public function register(): void
{
    $this->renderable(function (InvalidSignatureException $e) {
        return response()->view('error.link-expired', [], 403);
    });
}
```

The code goes in the `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` file.

you can of course return a route instead of a view, in your case `/email/verify`

Although it does not exactly utilizes `AuthorizationException` this is by far the easiest solution I was able to find to solve the same issue I had as the OP.

Honestly my App does not catch `AuthorizationException` for some reason. It could be worth trying with it as well, instead of `InvalidSignatureException` if this is very important to you.